# Inconsistant results with P5.JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have made a multiplayer painting app and it is confusing me. When you draw something on one client, it shows up good for them but for other people it has blocks around it. Ive been working on this for a while and it did not used to do this but I tore it apart and kept only the most important code and it still does it. All the server does it forward the messages it gets to the rest of the clients. Ive tried everything I see could be the problem but with no avail. I am using p5.js for this.

Javascript (client):

```
let ws; //Websocket
let mousePos; //Position of the mouse
let pmousePos; //Previous position of the mouse
let downPos = { //Position of the mouse when it was last pushed down
  "x":0,
  "y":0,
};
let canvas; //The canvas
let prevBrush; //Brush used before it was changes by another action.
let watchForColor = false; //Uses the onclick function to get the color hovered above on the next click
let previewShapes; //Selects the shape the draw() function shows a preview of
let previewShapesPos; //Preview shapes position
let recievedWhilePreviewing = []; //Shapes recieved from other clients while displaying a preview
let previousState; //State before previewing
let triangleStatus = 0; //Keep track how many clicks for making a triangle
let quadStatus = 0; //Keep track how many click for making a quadrilateral

//_("query_selector")
function _(selector){
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}
//Runs first to setup canvas5
function setup(){
  canvas = createCanvas(650, 500);
  canvas.parent("canvas-wrapper");
  background(255);
}
//Runs after mouse has been dragged
function mouseDragged(){
  let type = _('input[name="brush"]:checked').value;
  let size = parseInt(_("#pensize").value);
  let color = _("#pencolor").value;
  let strokec = _("#strokecolor").value;
  let strokes = _("#strokesize").value;
  if(type == "mouse"){
  } else if(type == "pencil"){
    fill(color);
    stroke(color);
    strokeWeight(1);
    line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY);
  } else if(type == "brush"){
    fill(color);
    stroke(color);
    strokeWeight(size);
    line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY);
  } else {
    return;
  }
  const paintData = {
    "paint": [
      {
        "x":mousePos.x - 43,
        "y":mousePos.y - 41,
        "px":pmousePos.x - 43,
        "py":pmousePos.y - 41,
        "size":size,
        "type":type,
        "color":color
      }
    ]
  }
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(paintData));
}
//Add other clients paint to canvas
function runPaint(p){
  if(previewShapes != null) return recievedWhilePreviewing.push(p);
  if(p.type == "mouse"){
  } else if(p.type == "pencil"){
    fill(p.color);
    stroke(p.color);
    strokeWeight(1);
    line(p.px, p.py, p.x, p.y);
  } else if(p.type == "brush"){
    fill(p.color);
    stroke(p.color);
    strokeWeight(p.size);
    line(p.px, p.py, p.x, p.y);
  } else if(p.type == "line"){
    fill(p.color);
    stroke(p.color);
    strokeWeight(p.size);
    line(p.px, p.py, p.x, p.y);
  } else if(p.type == "square"){
    fill(p.color);
    stroke(p.strokec);
    strokeWeight(p.strokes);
    rect(p.px, p.py, (p.x - p.px), (p.y - p.py))
  } else if(p.type == "circle"){
    fill(p.color);
    stroke(p.color);
    strokeWeight(1);
    circle(p.px, p.py, ((p.x - p.px) + (p.y - p.py)))
  } else if(p.type == "triangle"){
    fill(p.color);
    stroke(p.strokec);
    strokeWeight(p.strokes);
    triangle(p.px, p.py, p.pxt, p.pyt, p.pxth, p.pyth);
  } else {
    
  }
}

(async function() {
  ws = await connectToServer();
  createOwnCursor()
  //Runs on message recieve from websocket server
  ws.onmessage = (webSocketMessage) => {
    if(webSocketMessage.data.startsWith('msg:')) return newMessage(webSocketMessage.data.substring(4));
    const messageBody = JSON.parse(webSocketMessage.data.toString());
    if(messageBody.close){
      const r = _(`[data-sender='${messageBody.close}']`);
      r.parentNode.removeChild(r);
    } else if(messageBody.paint){
      const p = messageBody.paint[0];
      runPaint(p)
    } else {
      const cursor = getOrCreateCursorFor(messageBody);
      cursor.style.transform = `translate(${messageBody.x}px, ${messageBody.y}px)`;
    }
  };
  //Runs when the mouse moves
  document.body.onmousemove = (evt) => {
    const r = _(`[data-sender='self']`);
    r.style.transform = `translate(${evt.clientX - 5}px, ${evt.clientY - 5}px)`;
    const messageBody = { x: evt.clientX, y: evt.clientY };
    pmousePos = mousePos;
    mousePos = messageBody;
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(messageBody));
  };
  //Connect to websocket server
  async function connectToServer() {
    const ws = new WebSocket('wss://paintmp.lankdev.repl.co/ws');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const timer = setInterval(() => {
        if(ws.readyState === 1) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          resolve(ws);
        }
      }, 10);
    });
  }
  //Get or Create other clients cursors when called
  function getOrCreateCursorFor(messageBody) {
    const sender = messageBody.sender;
    const existing = _(`[data-sender='${sender}']`);
    if (existing) {
      return existing;
    }

    const template = document.getElementById('cursor');
    const cursor = template.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
    const svgPath = cursor.getElementsByTagName('path')[0];    

    cursor.setAttribute("data-sender", sender);
    svgPath.setAttribute('stroke', `hsl(${messageBody.color}, 50%, 50%)`);    
    svgPath.setAttribute('fill', `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`);
    document.body.appendChild(cursor);
    return cursor;
  }
  //Creates this client's cursor
  function createOwnCursor(){
    const template = document.getElementById('cursor');
    const cursor = template.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
    const svgPath = cursor.getElementsByTagName('path')[0];    

    cursor.setAttribute("data-sender", 'self');
    svgPath.setAttribute('fill', `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`);
    document.body.appendChild(cursor);
    return cursor;
  }
})();
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PaintMP</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://paintmp.lankdev.repl.co/assets/images/icons/pmp.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://paintmp.lankdev.repl.co/pages/beta/style.css">
    <script src="https://paintmp.lankdev.repl.co/assets/modules/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://paintmp.lankdev.repl.co/pages/beta/script.js"></script>
    <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sora:wght@500&display=swap');
      *{font-family: Sora;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body id="box">
    
    <template id="cursor">
      <svg viewBox="-4 -4 8 8" class="cursor">
        <path style="fill:#000;" stroke="#F00" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M-4 0-4 1-1 1-1 4 1 4 1 1 4 1 4-1 1-1 1-4-1-4-1-1-4-1-4 0"/>
      </svg>
    </template>
    
    <div class="controlsleft" id="ctrlleft">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="brush" class="brushtype" value="brush" checked>
        <img id="brush" class="leftimg selctrl noselect" src="https://paintmp.lankdev.repl.co/assets/images/icons/brush.png">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="canvascont" id="canvascont">
      <div id="canvas-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="settingscont" class="settingscont noselect">
      
      <button class="optionbox">
        <label class="container">
          <input type="checkbox" id="coloractive" checked="checked">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      Fill</button>
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="layerspacer"></div>
        <div class="layercont">
          <div id="color-picker-wrapper">
              <input type="color" oninput="colortxt.value=value" id="pencolor">
          </div>
          <input type="text" oninput="pencolor.value=value" id="colortxt">
        </div>
        <div class="layerspacer"></div>
        <div class="lower">
          <input type="range" value="15" min="0" max="100" id="pensize" oninput="rangenumber.value=value"/>
          <input type="number" id="rangenumber" min="0" max="100" value="15" oninput="pensize.value=value">
        </div>
      </div>

      <button class="optionbox">
        <label class="container">
          <input type="checkbox" id="strokeactive" checked="checked">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      Stroke</button>
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="layerspacer"></div>
        <div class="layercont">
          <div id="stroke-picker-wrapper">
              <input type="color" oninput="stroketxt.value=value" id="strokecolor">
          </div>
          <input type="text" oninput="strokecolor.value=value" id="stroketxt">
        </div>
        <div class="layerspacer"></div>
        <div class="lower">
          <input type="range" value="15" min="0" max="100" id="strokesize" oninput="rangenumberstroke.value=value"/>
          <input type="number" id="rangenumberstroke" min="0" max="100" value="15" oninput="strokesize.value=value">
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

NodeJS (backend):

```
wsServer.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
  const id = uuidv4();
  const color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
  const metadata = { id, color };

  clients.set(ws, metadata);

  ws.on('message', (messageAsString) => {
    const message = JSON.parse(messageAsString);
    const metadata = clients.get(ws);

    message.sender = metadata.id;
    message.color = metadata.color;

    wsServer.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
      if(client == ws) return;
      if (client.readyState === ws.OPEN) {
        client.send(JSON.stringify(message));
      }
    });

    if(message.paint != null){
      cache.push(message)
    }
  });
  ws.on("close", () => {
    let r = {
      "close":clients.get(ws).id,
    };
    [...clients.keys()].forEach((client) => {
      client.send(JSON.stringify(r));
    });
    clients.delete(ws);
    if(clients.size == 0){
      cache = [];
    };
  });
});
```

[How its supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfTNw.png)

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP4nZ.png)